# Ignore empty fields

Tags: bash, awk

Given this file

```
$ cat foo.txt
,,,,dog,,,,,111,,,,222,,,333,,,444,,,
,,,,cat,,,,,555,,,,666,,,777,,,888,,,
,,,,mouse,,,,,999,,,,122,,,133,,,144,,,
```

I can print the first field like so

```
$ awk -F, '{print $5}' foo.txt
dog
cat
mouse
```

However I would like to ignore those empty fields so that I can call like this

```
$ awk -F, '{print $1}' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
$ awk '{print $1}' FPAT=[^,]+ foo.txt
dog
cat
mouse
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this:

```
$ awk -F',+' '{print $2}' file
dog
cat
mouse
```

Similarly, you can use $3, $4 and $5 and so on.. $1 cannot be used in this case because the records begins with delimiter.

Comment: @sudo_O : No specific reason as such..you are right, it makes it clear inside..updating it...

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/^,*|,*$/,"");gsub(/,+/,",");print $1}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
,,,,dog,,,,,111,,,,222,,,333,,,444,,,
,,,,cat,,,,,555,,,,666,,,777,,,888,,,
,,,,mouse,,,,,999,,,,122,,,133,,,144,,,
```

execution:

```
> awk -F, '{gsub(/^,*|,*$/,"");gsub(/,+/,",");print $1}' temp
dog
cat
mouse
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the fields would be `,,,,dog,,foo,,,111,,,,222,,,333,,,444,,,`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete multiple repetition of a field with `tr -s 'field'`:

```
$ tr -s ',' < your_file
,dog,111,222,333,444,
,cat,555,666,777,888,
,mouse,999,122,133,144,
```

And then you can access to `dog`, etc with:

```
$ tr -s ',' < your_file | awk -F, '{print $2}'
dog
cat
mouse
```

Comment: I'd do `tr -s ',' < file` to drop the UUoC :]

Comment: I tried `tr -s ',' file` but did not work. I knew there could be a way, thanks @sudo_O!

Comment: Yup, `tr` only reads from `stdin` so redirection is needed when reading files!

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -anF,+ -e 'print "$F[1]\n"' foo.txt
dog
cat
mouse
```

this is no awk but you will get to use 1 instead of 2.